# Adding include paths to pip to build wheels of dlib

Tags: pip

Trying to install dlib using pip. But receive the following error, when building wheels

```
fatal error: cusolverDn.h: No such file or directory
```

I found the header in `/usr/local/cuda-11.6/targets/x86_64-linux/include` and tried to update the include paths using `--global-option`, but it didn't work.